# IOS/Objective-C: Change object behind detail view of tableview programmatically

Tags: ios, redraw, setneedsdisplay

In a master tableview-detail view controller app, after loading a detail view, I would like to let the user view the detail for a different item from the tableview if they wish.

To do this, I pass two objects to the detail view in `prepareForSegue` and use one of them to load the view.

If I want, I am able to change individual items on the screen one by one, for example, by changing `self.title = item.title` to `self.title = altitem.title`. My question, is, whether there is a way to reload the entire view using the alternative object?

I have read that `setNeedsDisplay` should reload the whole view, but it is not changing the object behind the view or at least the view on the screen  Here is my code currently:

```
//in prepareForSegue method in master tableview

destViewController.item=item;;
destViewController.altItem=altitem;

//in .h file of detail view

@property (nonatomic, strong) Items *item;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Items *altitem;

// in .m file of detailView

in viewDidLoad

self.title = item.title;

//my method to change object - NOT DOING ANYTING

-(void) reloadWithAltItem {
self.item = self.altitem;
[self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions.